# ServiceNow ui-component deploy not working

Tags: servicenow

I am creating a custom UI component for UI Builder. I have successfully setup the project.

But while trying to deploy the component using **"snc ui-component deploy"** I am getting error that **"Could not find an active connection to a ServiceNow instance."**

Service now account is open and running in my default browser. I even tried to create a named profile and deploy as below

**snc ui-component deploy --profile profile-name**

But it still gives me same error i.e. "Could not find an active connection to a ServiceNow instance."

ServiceNow version is **San Diego**

What possible issue this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout how to connect to ServiceNow instance via the now-cli first. This is how you connect with an instance:

```
now-cli login --username admin --password <password> --host https://<yourPDI>.service-now.com
```

I think the official tutorial will provide you with a lot of information how to get started: [Next Experience UI: Create a Project](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/learn/courses/quebec/app_store_learnv2_uiframework_quebec_now_experience_ui_framework/app_store_learnv2_uiframework_quebec_build_my_first_now_experience_ui_framework_custom_component/app_store_learnv2_uiframework_quebec_exercise_create_a_project)